# Using the instagram api with my own account's credentials

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a simple use case for the instagram api: I want to display media related to a specific tag. E.g. [`GET/tags/tbt/media/recent`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/). I do *not* need users to authenticate with Instagram to do this, I merely wish to use my own account and `access_token` to make the api requests.

Unfortunately, I've run into two problems:

1. I cannot test this API in sandbox due to the fact that the `public_content` scope is only available to approved applications.
2. My app submission was denied because I did not provide a screencast showcasing my usage of an instagram authentication flow (my use case does not have one, and I explained that I did not need users to authenticate).

Currently, the API seems geared towards larger, richer integrations, and doesn't leave a lot of space for applications like my own.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want given the new `access_token` only flow?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?